# Giving Syntax error in Scrapy (Python) - XPath

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I'm using Scrapy Crawler to extract some details like username, upvotes, join date etc.

I'm using XPath for extracting the contents from each user's webpage.

Code:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.http import Request
from scrapy.spiders import BaseSpider
from scrapy.http import FormRequest
from loginform import fill_login_form
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse

class UserSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'userspider'
    start_urls = ['<website-to-scrape>']
    #Getting the list of usernames
    user_names = ['Bob', 'Tom']  #List of Usernames

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UserSpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def parse(self, response):
        return [FormRequest.from_response(response,
                    formdata={'registerUserName': 'user', 'registerPass': 'password'},
                    callback=self.after_main_login)]

    def after_main_login(self, response):
        for user in self.user_names:
            user_url = 'profile/' + user
            yield response.follow(user_url, callback=self.parse_user_pages)

    def parse_user_pages(self, response):
        yield{
            "USERNAME": response.xpath('//div[contains(@class, "main") and contains(@class, "no-sky-main")]/h1[contains(@class, "thread-title")]/text()').extract_first()
            "UPVOTES": response.xpath('//div[contains(@class, "proUserInfoLabelLeft") and @id="proVotesCap"]/text()').extract()[0]
        }

if __name__ == "__main__":
    spider = UserSpider()
```

[Error looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vfwwb.png)

P.S. I have manually checked the syntax of my XPath on the Scrapy Shell and it was working fine

Is there anything that I'm not noticing in the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a `,` after your first dict element:

```
{"USERNAME": response.xpath(...).extract_first(),
 "UPVOTES": response.xpath(...).extract()[0]}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I have made a silly mistake thanks for pointing out!